# How do I get the "Copy view area" for CCRC as a variable in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

When attempting to set up an 'External Tool' in Eclipse, there are a great deal of variables that deal with project location, workspace location etc - but not any for reference to the Copy View Area - i.e. Where your CCRC view starts.

This would be very useful for referencing tools that may be in a VOB external to the Java Project you are working in within a view.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can retrieve the copy view area as a variable in Eclipse?

Thanks,

Stuart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, referencing an external path in done through a Linked Resource Variable, which you can then refer in your project through a **[linked folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300328/eclipse-attach-source-javadoc-to-a-library-via-a-local-property/300346#300346)**.
Your external tool launcher configuration can then use a '`project_path`' variable to reference it (or '`resource_loc`' to obtain the absolute file system path of a workspace relative path resource).

Now, regarding CCRC, I check (and launch my own CCRC right now).
However, a CCRC "web view" is actually a snapshot view, meaning the "Copy View Area" would actually refer in this case to the root of a snapshot view.
And there is no way to "deduce" the root of a snapshot view in ClearCase (actually, you can even have *several* roots for "one view"! Just copy the hidden .view file wherever you want, and that directory will become the new root of your unique snapshot view!)

Comment: No way of getting $copy_view_area from a CCRC view? Bah. That's not very good :S

Comment: It's also kinda sad that we seem to be the only ClearCase (you Jedi, I padawan) Admins on StackOverflow - I may as well e-mail you directly!

Comment: @Spedge: not true, other "knights" pop-up once in a while (for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917858/tool-to-list-all-source-safe-link-files/926685#926685 ). To contact me: vonc at laposte dot net. (but please keep posting questions here: it is hard enough to gain votes on a topic such as ClearCase ;) )